# OpenGL Models overriding previous ones

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have been trying to figure out this bug in my code for quite a while, and now I'm seeking help from stackoverflow! Anyway, I have created a class for the creation of a model in openGL. It handles the VBO, VAO, and EBO for a given model, but when I create two and display them, the second always overrides the previous one/ones I have no idea why, I showed it to a friend of mine, and together we figured out nothing. This is the model class:

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;
using System;

namespace YISOPENGLEVIL.Components.Objects
{
struct Vertex
{
    Vector3 Position;
    Vector3 Color;
    public Vertex(Vector3 position, Vector3 color)
    {
        Position = position;
        Color = color;
    }
}
class Model
{
    public int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    public Vertex[] Data;
    public int[] Indices;
    public Model() { }
    public Model(Vertex[] data, int[] indices)
    {
        Data = data;
        Indices = indices;

        VAO = GL.GenVertexArray();
        VBO = GL.GenBuffer();
        EBO = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, Data.Length * 24, Data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 24, 0);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 24, 12);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, EBO);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, Indices.Length * 4, Indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    }
    protected static Vector3 toVec3(Color4 c)
    {
        return new Vector3(c.R, c.G, c.B);
    }
    public void Render()
    {
        //GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, Data.Length);
        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
    }
}
}
```

and my Element class, which gets passed a Model then is used to display it,

```
using OpenTK;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4;

namespace YISOPENGLEVIL.Components.Objects
{
class Element
{
    private int transform;
    private int s;
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Rotation;
    private Matrix4 View;
    private Model Model;

    public Element(Model m, int Shader)
    {
        s = Shader;
        Model = m;
        Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Rotation = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
    public void Render()
    {
        var t = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(Position.X, Position.Y, Position.Z);
        var rx = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(Rotation.X);
        var ry = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(Rotation.Y);
        var rz = Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(Rotation.Z);

        View = t * rx * ry * rz;

        transform = GL.GetUniformLocation(s, "transform");
        GL.UniformMatrix4(transform, false, ref View);

        Model.Render();
    }
    public static void RenderAll()
    {

    }
}
}
```

and this is the implementation:

```
        m1 = new Cube(1.5f, Color4.Aqua);
        m2 = new Cube(1f, Color4.Red);
        e1 = new Element(m1, s.Program);
        e2 = new Element(m2, s.Program);
        e1.Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        e2.Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
```

and:

```
        e1.Render();
        e2.Render();
```

The cube class extends Model, and passes data into the Model constructor by private static methods that create the vertex arrays. The really weird thing is that if I put print statements it shows that both elements are being defined fine and have the correct data, the last always overrides the previous (there are two objects in the correct positions, but both displaying the red smaller cube). I don't get it... Any Ideas?

Screenshot of the program
[image: Screenshot of the program]

Comment: By the way, OpenGL isn’t evil.  Try opening a window in Direct3D

Comment: I know, but this is the millionth problem i've run into, so i liked the frustrated name

Comment: @QuantumAbyss Im encoutering the same issue right now, with the C OpenGL API, did you resolve it ?